# How come the following Google Script is not deleting contents in the range specified?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // current spreadsheet
  var old_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();                   // current (old) sheet
  var new_sheet = old_sheet.copyTo(ss);                  // make a copy
  new_sheet.setName(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-7:00', 'MM.dd.yy')); // set the name
  new_sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(new Date());         // set the cell A1
  new_sheet.getRange('A3:G12').clear({contentsOnly: true}); // clears content in A3:G12
  new_sheet.getRange('A20:G29').clear({contentsOnly: true}); // clears content in A20:G29
  old_sheet.hideSheet();                                 // hide the old sheet
}
```

For the 2 lines "new_sheet.getRange().clear(contents), it won't clear what is in the specified range.

I have recorded another macro:

```
function delete1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList('A3:G12').clear({contentsOnly: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A20:G29').clear({contentsOnly: true});
};
```

That does work when I click to delete the range (both with .getactiverangelist and .getrange)

I have tried to use .getRange and .getActiveRangeList, I've tried adding .getActive() to the front but can't get it to work:

```
new_sheet.getActive().getRange('A3:G12').clear({contentsOnly: true}); // clears content in A3:G12
```

I'm a bit lost as to why new_sheet.getRange('A1') works when I set the date in cell A1

But when I try to replicate this process to clear contents it is not deleting the contents.

Edit:

Here is a copy of the google sheet. I just nicknamed it "Test" and put in some sample data. The fields that I am trying to erase is the two tables, green one on top and blue one on the bottom

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d44qCOkrxj7116Na-e0sLj2eggoEYcVDwohcUiMa-eU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after copying

Comment: One explanation would be that the cells in question contain results from an array formula located above or to the left of the cells. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: For some reason, I was playing around with SpreadsheetApp.flush() but was not able to get it to work so I reverted the code back to what I have above. And now it deletes the contents in the table. How weird. I am so confused as to why it didn't do it before but it does it now.